# Maven Web project error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

Following is the error

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\akhil nambiar\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\CGSang does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
28 Feb, 2012 12:16:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
28 Feb, 2012 12:16:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
28 Feb, 2012 12:16:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/CGSang] startup failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\akhil nambiar\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\CGSang does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1035)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:432)
28 Feb, 2012 12:16:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
28 Feb, 2012 12:16:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
28 Feb, 2012 12:16:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/CGSang] startup failed due to previous errors
```

What could be the error. I installed M2E and M2WTP in eclipse.

Comment: Does the file mentioned in exception exist?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov no. only a directory called ROOT exists

Comment: Apparently, the problem is in this then.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov well what should I do? why do i need that directory? What files to put in there?

Comment: It looks like there is some problem with the plugin that resides there: org.eclipse.wst.server.core. Maybe you should try to reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if this is caused by the path in this case which contains spaces ? (Document base C:\Users\akhil nambiar\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\CGSang does not exist or is not a readable directory)

Comment: nope... its windows. spaces supported. i have projects in other directory in workspace

Comment: Have cleanly published the information to the server after refreshing ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.

Following are the commands to be typed in terminal/command prompt

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Reopen in eclipse. Right click the project and choose import into maven project.